# How to split a text file containing printer IP address and Text to send to that printer

Tags: bash, shell, unix, tcp

On a Linux server we receive a file which contains:

```
1. the printer IP address 
2. the Text (XML tags) to be sent to that printer using FTP
```

I need a bash shell script which can split the file and send the Text to the corresponding IP Address printer via FTP.

The file can contain several IP addresses followed by the Text

In the example shown: 
    First there is the IP address, terminated by separator | (this can be changed or removed). 
    Then we have the text to send to the printer, terminated by `</labels>`
    A second IP address and Text to send to that IP address.
    A third IP address and Text to send to that IP address.

```
12.123.12.123|
<?xml version="1.0" standalone="no"?>
<!DOCTYPE labels SYSTEM "label.dtd">
<labels _FORMAT="E:HOTDOC.ZPL" _QUANTITY="1" _PRINTERNAME="Printer 1" _JOBNAME="LBL101">
       <label>
                <variable name="TEXT1">30959</variable>
        </label>
        <label>
                <variable name="TEXT1">30960</variable>
        </label>
        <label>
                <variable name="TEXT1">30961</variable>
        </label>
</labels>
12.567.12.123|
<?xml version="1.0" standalone="no"?>
<!DOCTYPE labels SYSTEM "label.dtd">
<labels _FORMAT="E:HOTDOC.ZPL" _QUANTITY="1" _PRINTERNAME="Printer 1" _JOBNAME="LBL101">
        <label>
                <variable name="TEXT1">30962</variable>
        </label>
        <label>
                <variable name="TEXT1">30963</variable>
        </label>
</labels>
12.890.12.123|
<?xml version="1.0" standalone="no"?>
<!DOCTYPE labels SYSTEM "label.dtd">
<labels _FORMAT="E:HOTDOC.ZPL" _QUANTITY="1" _PRINTERNAME="Printer 1" _JOBNAME="LBL101">
        <label>
                <variable name="TEXT1">309625</variable>
        </label>
</labels>
```

In the past we had one file for the IP address (printer.txt) and a separate file for the Text (xmlfile.txt). I was using the below script. But now, we have several printers, and therefore needed to add the IP into the file to define the destination.

```
#!/bin/sh
HOST='12.123.12.212'
USER='anonymous'
FILE='/a01/folder/xmlfile.txt'

ftp -n $(cat /a01/folder/printer.txt) /a01/folder/ <<END_SCRIPT
quote USER $USER
put $FILE
quit
END_SCRIPT
exit 0
```

Comment: This is a much bigger change than you seem to realize. Before, you didn't have to parse the XML stream at all; now you do. Why not have separate files for each printer/XML pair?

Comment: I agree with you, but I need to know which file must be sent to which printer IP. Currently the process is parsing the source (a database record) once every minute, and then creating the file.

Answer (score 0):

Keep separate files for each document, with just the XML.

Create one text file table that is the address and the name of the matching file.

```
12.123.12.123|/path/to/file1
12.567.12.123|/path/to/file2
```

Then your script can read the table and know where each datafile is, and can read the datafile without the design change breaking your XML integrity.

Comment: Thank you for this good suggestion, I was indeed wondering how to keep the IP and file linked. I will check if I can generate different filenames  file1,file2.

Comment: Sometimes a small design change can save you a lot of time and effort. ;) If it works, please accept the solution. Let me know if you need more input.